# Query large volume of data for web page display

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to Oracle (know some basic SQL), but the task is somehow assigned to me.

My task is to optimize a query. It joins some large tables (query is time consuming) and returns the result to a webpage (paging can be used).

My question is what direction should I look into? It would be better if links can be provided.

Here is some details:

**Optimized methods taken**

```
index on dayNum, timeNum, entityID columns
```

**Number of rows:**

- time_seq:  100,000
- indicator_set: 50,000,000
- tity amount: 1,000

**Query:**

```
select * 
  from time_seq seq,  
       (  
        select entityID, 
               dayNum,
               timeNum,
               sum(ind1) sum_ind1, 
               avg(ind2) avg_ind2, 
               max(ind3) max_ind3  
          from indicator_set  
         group by entityID, dayNum, timeNum 
         -- the dayNum timeNum are grouped to the time sequence standard 
         -- in time_seq table  
        ) sum  
where seq.entityID=sum.entityID  
  and seq.dayNum=sum.dayNum  
  and seq.timeNum=sum.timeNum
```

**Table time_seq**

```
entityID, dayNum, timeNum
--------------------------------
object1, 20110818, 220000  
object1, 20110818, 223000  
object1, 20100818, 230000  
object1, 20110819, 220000  
object1, 20110819, 223000  
object1, 20100819, 230000 
object2, 20110818, 220000  
object2, 20110818, 223000   
object2, 20100818, 230000  
object2, 20110819, 220000  
object2, 20110819, 223000  
object2, 20100819, 230000
```

**Table indicator_set**

```
entityID, dayNum, timeNUm, ind1, ind2, ind3
--------------------------------------------
object1, 20110818, 220000, 23,34,23
object1, 20110818, 220500, 23,54,543
object1, 20110818, 220530, 23,54,543
object1, 20110818, 220610, 23,54,543
object1, 20110818, 222900, 23,54,543
...
```

PS: sorry I didn't provide exact format/detail of the table and query. Just too complicated.

cheers~

Comment: Am i missing something or does the SUM window query not have the columns "daynum" or "timenum" returned in it? Therefore it cannot equi-join to table time_seq on these columns so the query won't work as written?

Comment: I added `dayNum` and `timeNum` to the `SELECT` list in your inline view.  That would be required for the query to compile so I guessed you inadvertently left those out in your post.

Comment: Which table is the index on daynum, timenum and entityid columns, both time_seq and indicator_set? Out of interest, could you post the explain plan you are getting too?

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with the results of this query?  Assuming that the query returns on the order of 100,000 rows (I assume that the join does not eliminate a substantial number of the rows in `TIME_SEQ`), the query doesn't make a lot of sense.  You're returning 100,000 unordered rows to a user via a web page-- there is no way that a human would ever page through 100,000 rows and there is no way that it makes sense to present those rows unordered (or to order them in the middle tier).

It would very rarely make sense to try to aggregate 50 million rows of data on the fly in order to populate a web page.  That's going to be an inherently slow operation-- if users are expecting a response in a second or two, you don't have time to read and aggregate 50 million rows.  You could potentially create a materialized view on `INDICATOR_SET` that could be used to pre-aggregate the data.  That will make inserts and updates slower but should speed up your query.

Of course, even if you pre-aggregate the 50 million rows down to just 100,000 rows, you're still trying to join two 100,000 row tables and send 100,000 unordered rows to the client which is unlikely to be reasonable.  You could potentially add an `ORDER BY` clause so that the rows come in a reasonable order but that is generally going to add time to the query since you're introducing an extra sort.  There may be ways to optimize that depending on what you intend to sort by.  However, I'd still come back to the fundamental problem that returning 100,000 rows to a human client is fundamentally not the right approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. First, you make a very good point, maybe we are just wrong at the beginning. 

Let say we don't need to return all those rows. I need to return the largest sum(ind1). I still need to join them, calculate, order (desc) them all, then return the first record, right? In this case, the query is still slow. So, beside pre-aggregate, what's the other area I should look into?

thank you. I got to sleep now, ha.

ps: can I ask you some questions?
1. how can you edit my post (thank you for that)? 
2. is writing this comment a proper way to answer other's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Would linking the indicator_set and time_seq tables within the subquery limit the amount of rows to be grouped in the large indicator_set table?

```
SELECT *
  FROM time_seq seq,
       (  SELECT ind.entityid,
                 ind.dayNum,
                 ind.timeNum,
                 SUM( ind.ind1 ),
                 AVG( ind.ind2 ),
                 MAX( ind.ind3 )
            FROM indicator_set ind,
                 time_seq ts
           WHERE ind.entity_id = ts.entityid
             AND ind.daynum    = ts.daynum
             AND ind.timenum   = ts.timenum
        GROUP BY ind.entityid,
                 ind.daynum,
                 ind.timenum) SUM
 WHERE seq.entityid = SUM.entityid
   AND seq.daynum   = SUM.daynum
   AND seq.timenum  = SUM.timenum
```

The outher query would still ensure that only the records from the time_seq table would be returned from the query though.

Is this helpful?

EDIT: By the way, i'd use a better table alias than SUM as it is an oracle function.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, the indicator_set has to be grouped into the time_seq format (which is hourly based, e.g.) first before they can join together.
ps: All names are just made up by myself, for easy typing.

Comment: Why when you are both grouping and linking on those exact columns?

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the group exactly as it is. It should (something likes) be:
group ((int)timeNum/10000)*10000

dayNum is similar, but can be ignored at the moment.

The time_seq is hourly based, but the indicator_set is minute based, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a materialized view based on your query:

```
create materialized view mv as
select entityID, 
               dayNum,
               timeNum,
               sum(ind1) sum_ind1, 
               avg(ind2) avg_ind2, 
               max(ind3) max_ind3  
          from indicator_set  
         group by entityID, dayNum, timeNum;
```

This table would be smaller. You can create your indexes also in this materialized view. Your select would be something like this:

```
select * 
  from time_seq seq,  
      mv sum  
where seq.entityID=sum.entityID  
  and seq.dayNum=sum.dayNum  
  and seq.timeNum=sum.timeNum;
```

Your materialized view could be refresehed in fast mode, normal, etc... If you want some more intormation, take a look:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6002.htm

http://orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Materialized_Views